# Invalid input still updates the total

Tags: java

[EDIT]
It seems like moving this piece of code somewhere else would solve my issue, but I can't see to figure out where..

```
    if (numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE || numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE || totalPeople < MIN_PEOPLE) { 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data"); 
    }
```

Could someone explain why my 'total people' still gets updated when I enter an invalid value such as a negative number? Also, why would the total people get printed anyway if the user enters invalid input?

```
  final int MAX_PEOPLE = 65; 
  final int MIN_PEOPLE = 0;
  int totalPeople = 0; 
  int numLeaving = 0;
  int numEntering = 0; 
  boolean invalid = true;
  while (invalid) { 
     String question = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("leaving or entering?");          
     try  {  
        // Decrease the total if people are leaving
        if (question.equalsIgnoreCase("leaving")) {
           numLeaving = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number leaving:"));
           totalPeople -= numLeaving;                       
        }
        // Increase the total if people are entering
        else if (question.equalsIgnoreCase("entering")) {
           numEntering = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("number entering:"));
           totalPeople += numEntering;                       
        }
        else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"'leaving' or 'entering' only");
        }   
        // Prints out current total before capacity is exceeded          
        if (totalPeople > MAX_PEOPLE) {
           invalid = false;
           totalPeople = totalPeople - numEntering;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Capacity exceeded\n" + "Total people = " + totalPeople);
        }  
        else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total people = " + totalPeople);              
        }       
     } 
     catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"numbers only");
     }                        
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason 'totalPeople' is still being updated is because you are not checking if it is a valid input in the beginning your loop. If I were you I would add the following code in the beginning of your while loop:

```
if(totalPeople < 0){
   invalid = false;
   break;
}
```

Also I find it a bit misleading naming a boolean in the negative. Having a boolean named 'invalid' being true would make one question, "Does the true stand for valid or invalid?"

I would name the boolean as 'valid' instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't say anywhere that a negative number is invalid input. -= and += operators will just work fine for negative ints.

[Edit]
Suppose you select "leaving" and provide numLeaving =-65 tehn total people will be 0-(-65) = 65. You will enter the if block of below code and not the else blocks which checks for negative inputs.

```
    if (totalPeople > MAX_PEOPLE) {
       invalid = false;
       totalPeople = totalPeople - numEntering;
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Capacity exceeded\n" + "Total people = " + totalPeople);
    } 
    else if (numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE || numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE || totalPeople < MIN_PEOPLE) { 
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data"); 
    } 
    else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total people = " + totalPeople);              
    }
```

Comment: else if (numLeaving < MIN_PEOPLE || numEntering < MIN_PEOPLE || totalPeople < MIN_PEOPLE) { 
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid data"); 
        }

Wouldn't that be it?